# Exchange 2010 - How could a mailbox be forwarding to users despite in mail-flow settings, delivery options, mail forwarding is not set?

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2010, email

The mailbox that is forwarding and the mailboxes it's forwarding to were migrated from Exchange 2003 to 2010.

Maybe the attributes are actually set but are not showing correctly in EMC for some reason?

Comment: Have you checked for any rules in the email client?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have the "forwarding" mailbox's email address added as an email alias on the receiving mailbox?